# Spark streaming: un structured records

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

We are consuming data from **EventHub** using streaming.
Incoming stream contains **JSON** records of various types (around 400 different types)

Each record will be categorized using **ProductId** property.

example (Incoming stream of records):

```
record1 - { productId: 101, colA: "some-val", colB: "some-val" }
record2 - { productId: 104, colC: "some-val", colD: "some-val" }
record3 - { productId: 202, colA: "some-val", colD: "some-val", colF: "some-val" }
record3 - { productId: 342, colH: "some-val", colJ: "some-val", colK: "some-val" }
```

Number of properties in each record varies, but record having similar **productId** will have exact same number of properties.

ProductId ranges from (1 - 400), number of properties in record will be upto 50.

I want to read above stream of JSON record & write to different **parquet/delta locations** like

```
    Location(Delta/Parquet)             Records
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    /mnt/product-101        Contains all records with productId - 101
    /mnt/product-104        Contains all records with productId - 104
    /mnt/product-202        Contains all records with productId - 202
    /mnt/product-342        Contains all records with productId - 342
```

1) How to create DataFrame/Dataset from stream containing different types of record?

2) Will it be possible using single spark stream & writing to different delta/parquet location ?

Comment: I assume that `/mnt/product-101` is going eventually all have the same columns (properties) in the end? If so, does that mean there can be a schema for `product-101`, `product-102`, etc?

Comment: @DanielHinojosa you are correct all records with same productId will have same columns. I'm unsure about how to use schema for product-101 and 102, if it works without schema it will be good.

Comment: So, just thinking out loud.  You can always do read as a text file (not csv, or json) which would just read the lines of text. Then convert it into a tuple of product-#, and then the rest of the data parsed.  You can then do a `groupBy` so that all the products are grouped and then you can possibly create a `DataFrame`, since they will all be the same.  Then write to a text file using the product-# as a prefix. What a fun challenge

Answer (score 0):

Please note the using this method should work however it will generate lots of sparse data.

First create a StructType with all the columns combined.

```
  val schema = new StructType().add("productId", LongType)
  .add("colA", StringType).add("colB", StringType)
  .add("colC", StringType)....
```

Then create a stream using this schema and the from_json function.

```
val df1 = df.select(from_json('value, schema).alias("tmp"))
.select("tmp.*")
```

Finally use partitionBy to write partitioned parquet files.

```
val query1 = df1 
.writeStream 
.format("parquet") 
.option("path", "/mnt/product/") 
.option("checkpointLocation","/tmp/checkpoint")
.partitionBy("productId").start()
```

This will generate rows with all the columns. The columns that weren't originally in the json input will be marked as null. Parquet supports writing nulls. But it would be better if you filter them first.